# valueerror: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not index of "datetime"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm hitting a snag on something with matplotlib.pyplot which is perplexing.

On a DataCamp course that I'm taking, the solution to the answer is the following code:

```
# Scatterplot with color relating to time
prices.plot.scatter('EBAY', 'YHOO', c=prices.index, 
                cmap=plt.cm.viridis, colorbar=False)
plt.show()
```

and the prices pandas dataframe (it's the NYSE dataset from Kaggle):

```
                EBAY       YHOO
date                            
2010-01-04  23.900000  17.100000
2010-01-05  23.650000  17.230000
2010-01-06  23.500000  17.170000
2010-01-07  23.229998  16.700001
2010-01-08  23.509999  16.700001
```

now in the DataCamp solution, it works and it produces a plot, but when I try to replicate it on my own using PyCharm, I get this error message:

> ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not Index(['2010-01-04', '2010-01-05', ...

Any ideas why it's not working??

Here's the figure that was generated by the code in DataCamp:

[image]

Comment: From the documentation it says c can be.... `A scalar or sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap and norm.` I'm guessing you need to convert the string indices to integer values.

Comment: @Chrispresso: you're right that the string data type of the Index is the issue, and even a DatetimeIndex will work here as well as what you suggest, integer values, would work.

Answer (score 0):

The error message could be clearer, I think.

The issue is apparent from how the Index is shown there, though: you have an `object` or `str` Index instead of a DatetimeIndex.

If you just do this before your call to `.scatter()` you'll be back on track:

```
import pandas as pd

prices.index = pd.to_datetime(prices.index)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, but it is ALREADY converted to a datetime when I read the dataset from csv file.using the parameters of "parse_dates" and "index_col" set to 'date'.